# Running build via gitlab ci / docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have successfully installed `Gitlab CI` and also linked it with my `gitlab`. I have also configured shared runners using `docker` with a `ruby-2.2` image with `mysql` service.

Following was what I executed to configure a runner by referring https://about.gitlab.com/2015/04/17/unofficial-gitlab-ci-runner/:

```
$ gitlab-ci-multi-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://my.gitlab.ip/" \
  --registration-token "REGISTRATION_TOKEN" \
  --description "ruby-mysql" \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image ruby:2.2 --docker-mysql latest
```

I have a sample Ruby / Rails application and for some reason the runner doesn't run the build. Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: ruby:2.2

services:
  - mysql:latest

before_script:
  - ruby -v
  - gem install bundler
  - cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
  - cp config/secrets.yml.example config/secrets.yml
  - bundle install

spec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec
  tags:
    - ruby-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the first line `image: ruby:2.2` of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

I had a similar issue where the CI reported a success, yet didn't do any work.
I used the lint provided on http://my.domain/lint
It flagged "image" and "stage/stages" as not correct.
That's why I think removing the first line will help you.

I think the problem is that the community version doesn't recognize the keywords yet.